# how to grant different permissions for different users on same instance

Tags: grails, permissions, acl

In my grails application I installed spring security acl and its working fine. I have one domain class customer and three roles i.e., admin,sales,others. 
How to grant permissions for different users on the same domain instance, i.e., For ROLE_ADMIN(create, read, delete and write), for ROLE_SALES(create, read) and ROLE_OTHERS(create,read,write).

Example: x is instance of customer created by admin role, who have permission to write, delete,read.
For the same x instance, how to grant permissions read,write for sale role and create,read, write permission for other role

Comment: You can use anotations in the controller for the access control in the controller actions

Answer (score 2):

You can place `@Secured` authorization annotations at the class level or the method level. That way you can lock down your controller methods to certain roles. For example, if you have a Thing domain class that you want to control access on, then you can annotate its controller this way:

```
class ThingController {
    @Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_SALES', 'ROLE_OTHERS'])
    create() {
      // creation logic
    }

    @Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_SALES', 'ROLE_OTHERS'])
    read() {
      // read logic
    }

    @Secured('ROLE_ADMIN')
    delete() {
      // delete logic
    }

    @Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_OTHERS'])
    write() {
      // write logic
    }
}
```

[Here](http://blog.springsource.org/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/) is a good intro to Grails Spring Security article (look under "Adding Access Control" and "Annotations"). [And here](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/5%20Configuring%20Request%20Mappings%20to%20Secure%20URLs.html) is the official Grails Spring Security documentation on the subject.